# How do I set it such that the pan recogniser increases a value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

How do I set it such that the pan recogniser increases an Int variable when swiping right and then decreases the existing variable when sliding left.

```
@IBAction func customiseWhiteBalance(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // Insert gesture value change here.... 
    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {

        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
        print(translation)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy:

1: Add a counter:

```
var counter = 0
```

2: Declare your gestures and add them to your view (or where you need them)

```
let right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didViewSwipe(_:)))
right.direction = .right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(right)

let left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didViewSwipe(_:)))
left.direction = .left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(left)
```

3: Get the gesture and start the counting

```
func didViewSwipe(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
            counter = counter + 1
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            if counter > 0{
               counter = counter - 1
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```